# Why does model.evaluate() not yield the same accuracy as computing it manually using a for-loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

After following the transfer learning tutorial on [Tensorflow's site](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning), I have a question about how model.evaluate() works in comparison to calculating accuracy by hand.

At the very end, after fine-tuning, in the Evaluation and prediction section, we use `model.evaluate()` to calculate the accuracy on the test set as follows:

```
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_dataset)
print('Test accuracy :', accuracy)
6/6 [==============================] - 2s 217ms/step - loss: 0.0516 - accuracy: 0.9740
Test accuracy : 0.9739583134651184
```

Next, we generate predictions manually from one batch of images from the test set as part of a visualization exercise:

```
# Apply a sigmoid since our model returns logits
predictions = tf.nn.sigmoid(predictions)
predictions = tf.where(predictions < 0.5, 0, 1)
```

However, it's also possible to extend this functionality to calculate predictions across the entire test set and compare them to the actual values to yield an average accuracy:

```
all_acc=tf.zeros([], tf.int32) #initialize array to hold all accuracy indicators (single element)
for image_batch, label_batch in test_dataset.as_numpy_iterator():
    predictions = model.predict_on_batch(image_batch).flatten() #run batch through model and return logits
    predictions = tf.nn.sigmoid(predictions) #apply sigmoid activation function to transform logits to [0,1]
    predictions = tf.where(predictions < 0.5, 0, 1) #round down or up accordingly since it's a binary classifier
    accuracy = tf.where(tf.equal(predictions,label_batch),1,0) #correct is 1 and incorrect is 0
    all_acc = tf.experimental.numpy.append(all_acc, accuracy)
all_acc = all_acc[1:]  #drop first placeholder element
avg_acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.dtypes.cast(all_acc, tf.float16)) 
print('My Accuracy:', avg_acc.numpy()) 
My Accuracy: 0.974
```

Now, if `model.evaluate()` generates predictions by applying a sigmoid to the logit model outputs and using a threshold of 0.5 like the tutorial suggests, my manually-calculated accuracy should equal the accuracy output of Tensorflow's `model.evaluate()` function. This is indeed the case for the tutorial. My Accuracy: 0.974 = accuracy from `model.evaluate()` function. However, when I try this same code with a model trained using the same convolutional base as the tutorial, but different gabor images (not cats & dogs like the tutorial), my accuracy no longer equals the `model.evaluate()` accuracy:

```
current_set = set17 #define set to process. 
all_acc=tf.zeros([], tf.float64) #initialize array to hold all accuracy indicators (single element)
loss, acc = model.evaluate(current_set) #now test the model's performance on the test set
for image_batch, label_batch in current_set.as_numpy_iterator():
    predictions = model.predict_on_batch(image_batch).flatten() #run batch through model and return logits
    predictions = tf.nn.sigmoid(predictions) #apply sigmoid activation function to transform logits to [0,1]
    predictions = tf.where(predictions < 0.5, 0, 1) #round down or up accordingly since it's a binary classifier
    accuracy = tf.where(tf.equal(predictions,label_batch),1,0) #correct is 1 and incorrect is 0
    all_acc = tf.experimental.numpy.append(all_acc, accuracy)
all_acc = all_acc[1:]  #drop first placeholder element
avg_acc = tf.reduce_mean(all_acc)
print('My Accuracy:', avg_acc.numpy()) 
print('Tf Accuracy:', acc) 
My Accuracy: 0.832
Tf Accuracy: 0.675000011920929
```

Does anyone know why there would be a discrepancy? Does the model.evaluate() *not* use a sigmoid? Or does it use a different threshold than 0.5? Or perhaps it's something else I'm not considering? Please note, my new model was trained using Gabor images, which are different than the cats and dogs from the tutorial, but the code was the same.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: the images you feed to the model were new to the model and it was never trained on them. So here comes the model tunning that my model works so well on the training data set and okay to my test set, but not so well on new data. So you would need to hyper-tune your model parameters and then check again on new images it works better or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated the post to be more clear. I did train this separate model on the new images. I followed the tutorial exactly, just with different images. The question is about why the two accuracy methods applied on the same test set in the same model give different results.